# Rotativa HTML to PDF on ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, pdf

I'm using [Rotativa](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/818197/Generate-PDF-in-ASP-NET-MVC-Using-Rotativa) resources to create PDF files from my HTML page on an MVC ASP.NET project. Here is my code
...........

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult DownloadCertificate()
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult DownloadViewPDF()
{
   return new Rotativa.ViewAsPdf("DownloadCertificate") { FileName = "TestViewAsPdf.pdf" };
}
```

priblem is it not generating my desire view's pdf.instate of it its generating my home page pdf..

my view for `ActionResult DownloadCertificate()` action  =>

```
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "DownloadCertificate";
        Layout = "";
    }
    <html>
    <head id="Head1">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />
        <title>
            Krogarna.se Certificate
        </title>
        <style type="text/css" media="print">
            {
                left: 0px !important;
                width: 11in !important;
                height: 8.5in !important;
                font-size: 107% !important;
            }
        </style>

        <style type="text/css" media="all">
            #top {
                height: 100%;
            }

            #position_me {
                left: 0;
            }

            .SlideBackGround {
                height: 650px;
                width: 880px;
                position: fixed;
                margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
                background-color: white;
                background-image: url(http://dotnet.ondev.com/ft63/content/sections/certificates/upload/krogarnase/frame.png);
                background-size: 880px 650px;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                z-index: 2;
                filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='http://dotnet.ondev.com/ft63/content/sections/certificates/upload/krogarnase/frame.png',sizingMethod='scale');
                -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='frame.png',sizingMethod='scale')";
            }

            .MiddlePart {
                height: 170px;
                width: 670px;
                position: fixed;
                left: 125px;
                top: 80px;
                background-image: url(http://dotnet.ondev.com/ft63/content/sections/certificates/upload/krogarnase/middle_part.png);
                background-size: 670px 170px;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                z-index: 5;
                filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='http://dotnet.ondev.com/ft63/content/sections/certificates/upload/krogarnase/middle_part.png',sizingMethod='scale');
                -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='middle_part.png',sizingMethod='scale')";
            }

            .Seal {
                height: 90px;
                width: 90px;
                position: fixed;
                left: 415px;
                top: 420px;
                background-image: url(http://dotnet.ondev.com/ft63/content/sections/certificates/upload/krogarnase/sigill.png);
                background-size: 90px 90px;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                z-index: 5;
                filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='http://dotnet.ondev.com/ft63/content/sections/certificates/upload/krogarnase/sigill.png',sizingMethod='scale');
                -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='sigill.png',sizingMethod='scale')";
            }

            .Ribbon {
                width: 60px;
                height: 90px;
                position: fixed;
                left: 435px;
                top: 520px;
                background-image: url(http://dotnet.ondev.com/ft63/content/sections/certificates/upload/krogarnase/band.png);
                background-size: 60px 90px;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                z-index: 5;
                filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='http://dotnet.ondev.com/ft63/content/sections/certificates/upload/krogarnase/band.png',sizingMethod='scale');
                -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='band.png',sizingMethod='scale')";
            }

            .Signature {
                width: 180px;
                height: 90px;
                position: fixed;
                left: 582px;
                top: 517px;
                background-image: url(http://dotnet.ondev.com/ft63/content/sections/certificates/upload/krogarnase/signature.png);
                background-size: 180px 90px;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                z-index: 11;
                filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='http://dotnet.ondev.com/ft63/content/sections/certificates/upload/krogarnase/signature.png',sizingMethod='scale');
                -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='signature.png',sizingMethod='scale')";
            }

            .DateLine {
                width: 300px;
                position: fixed;
                left: 112px;
                top: 570px;
                z-index: 11;
            }

            .ExaminerLine {
                width: 300px;
                position: fixed;
                left: 500px;
                top: 570px;
                z-index: 11;
            }

            .ExaminerText {
                width: 270px;
                position: fixed;
                left: 632px;
                top: 585px;
                color: #8B7B67;
                z-index: 11;
            }

            .DateText {
                width: 270px;
                position: fixed;
                left: 232px;
                top: 585px;
                z-index: 11;
                color: #8B7B67;
            }

            .ParagraphSmall {
                height: 200px;
                width: 500px;
                position: fixed;
                left: 200px;
                top: 350px;
                font-size: 13px;
                text-align: center;
                z-index: 11;
                color: #8B7B67;
            }

            .ParagraphMedium {
                height: 200px;
                width: 420px;
                position: fixed;
                left: 240px;
                top: 260px;
                font-size: 14px;
                text-align: center;
                z-index: 11;
                color: #8B7B67;
            }

            .HeadingLarge {
                height: 200px;
                width: 600px;
                position: fixed;
                left: 330px;
                top: 130px;
                font-size: 66px;
                z-index: 11;
                color: #8B7B67;
            }

            .MiddleLine {
                width: 720px;
                position: fixed;
                left: 100px;
                top: 330px;
                z-index: 11;
                color: #8B7B67;
            }

            .StudentName {
                font-weight: bold;
                height: 200px;
                width: 720px;
                position: fixed;
                left: 100px;
                top: 310px;
                font-size: 18px;
                text-align: center;
                z-index: 11;
                color: #8B7B67;
            }

            .CompletionDate {
                position: fixed;
                left: 225px;
                top: 555px;
                z-index: 11;
                color: #8B7B67;
                text-align: center;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="SlideBackGround">
        </div>

        <div class="MiddlePart">
        </div>

        <div class="HeadingLarge">Kursintyg</div>

        <div class="ParagraphMedium">
            HÄRMED INTYGAS
            ATT NEDANSTÅENDE PERSON KLARAT UTBILDNINGEN
            SERVERINGSTILLSTÅND
        </div>
        <div class="ParagraphSmall">
            Ni har visat prov på förståelse och kunnighet inom området alkoholservering. De 4 delar
            som avhandlats är: alkoholpolitik, tillsyn, servering samt mat, lokal och utrustning. Ni har
            efter denna utbildning de teoretiska kunskaper som krävs för att servera alkoholhaltiga
            drycker.
        </div>

        <div class="Seal"></div>

        <div class="Ribbon"></div>

        <hr class="DateLine" />

        <hr class="ExaminerLine" />

        <hr class="MiddleLine" />

        <div class="DateText">Datum</div>

        <div class="ExaminerText">Examiner</div>

        <div class="Signature"></div>

        <div id="CompletionDatePanel" class="CompletionDate">

            <span id="CompletionDateLabel">1/1/2014</span>

        </div>

        <div id="StudentNamePanel" class="StudentName">

            <span id="StudentNameLabel">John Doe</span>

        </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

now instate of creating above views pdf it is generating my home(login) view ..cant make any sense why ...

[image]
if there anyone who can help me about this.or can give me any tip how to get rid of this . or why i have done wrong. this will be greatfull.thanks in advance.....

Comment: How do you call DownloadAsPDF?

Comment: Check if you have any authorize filter which causes it to go to login page

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Hoping someone could help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Rotativa is running as a different as the one logged into the app, thus, when Rotativa tries to display the page to generate the pdf, asp.mvc tells that that use users is not authenticated and redirects to the home page.

To avoid that issue, you have to autorize all users to excecute the action:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult DownloadCertificate()
{
    return View();
}
```